# PHP image output suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, image, image-processing, php-gd

I have a file that manipulates images before they are output to the browser.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/_content/_constants.php');
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/_content/_functions.php');

    function hex2rgb($hex) {
       $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

       if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
          $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
          $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
          $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
       } else {
          $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
          $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
          $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
       }
       $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
       //return implode(",", $rgb); // returns the rgb values separated by commas
       return $rgb; // returns an array with the rgb values
    }

    /*-- Get the hex color code from the URL query --*/
    $rgb = hex2rgb((isset($_GET["color1"]) && $_GET["color1"] != '' ? $_GET["color1"] : "C9AA14"));

    /*-- Get the image file --*/
    $im = imagecreatefrompng (BASE."/_content/images/".$_GET["img"]);

    /*-- Preserve transparency --*/
    imageAlphaBlending($im, false);
    imageSaveAlpha($im, true);


    //$index = imagecolorclosest( $im,  0,0,0 ); // get original color
        //imagecolorset($im,imagecolorat($im,8,8), $rgb2[0],$rgb2[1],$rgb2[2] ); // SET COLOR OF ICON SYMBOL

    /*-- Apply the colorizing filter --*/
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $rgb[0],$rgb[1],$rgb[2], 0);

    /*-----------------------------------------------
    * If the image has a symbol/foreground 
    * on it, such as the audio/video icons, 
    * this sets the color of that symbol
    *
    * Not needed for single color images
    */
    //imagefilltoborder($im, 18, 21, imagecolorat($im,23,10), imagecolorallocate($im,0,0,0));  


    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagePng($im);


?>
```

As of a few days ago, whenever I try to load any images through this file, I get `The image {path-to-file} cannot be displayed because it contains errors`.

I've searched for answers to this issue and it seems just about everybody who gets this error is doing so because they're outputting stuff before `header()`, which is not the problem in my case.  I know something must have changed server-side because this was working fine for a long time, and then suddenly it just stopped working.  I tested the script on another server and it worked fine.

I ran a GD support test script on the server with these results:

```
GD is supported by your server!
GD Version          Yes
FreeType Support    Yes
FreeType Linkage    Yes
T1Lib Support       No
GIF Read Support    Yes
GIF Create Support  Yes
JPEG Support        Yes
PNG Support         Yes
WBMP Support        Yes
XPM Support         No
XBM Support         Yes
JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support    No
```

The main problem I have is that I really don't know enough about server requirements for PHP GD functionality, so what I need is some direction as to what I should look at as possible culprits in this case.  What could possibly have caused this to break?

Comment: What server? I ask because there is a bug in latest MAMP (Apache Mysql PHP for MacOs) and I had problems with all image generation stuff before reverting to an old version. Same code worked fine on remote server. Try your code on another server. What have you done "a few days ago" that changed the situation, if it worked before?

Comment: I did say I tried it on another server, and it works fine there.  I have been doing a lot of work on a site, but it's all just PHP/HTML stuff that shouldn't actually be changing anything on the server.  The only thing that even remotely could be related was a change I made with the .htaccess file, but I tested that (reverted it, and even removed it) and the problem persisted.

Comment: Is this the server info you asked for?  Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7

Comment: try replacing the header with a plaintext or html one and see what appears in the body of the message. Change header("Content-type: image/png"); with header("Content-type: text/plain"); and try to spot errors in the resulting text page. If PHP shoots a Notice in the middle of your image code you will see it

Comment: Good idea.  Well, I tried this, and it prompted a file download, so I opened it in Notepad and it just looks like raw image data.  I also tried opening this with an image viewer and it just showed the same raw 'text' data.

Comment: No PHP "Notice" or Error (like memory exausted at the end) along the whole page? Nothing suspicious? Scroll it all.. (if you don't want to open with an editor use header("Content-type: text/html"); or just remove the header call)

Comment: SpecialK's answer below solved the issue perfectly.  Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before sending the header with the file type try clearing the buffer:

```
// clean the output buffer
//http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php#75694
ob_clean();

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

Comment: This fixed it!  Thank you very much for this incredibly easy solution.  I'm glad it was something so simple.  Although, I still wonder why it had worked for so long without `ob_clean()` and suddenly stopped.  Any ideas?

Comment: When I ran into the problem it was even more strange as it worked on one website and not another and they were both running under the same LAMP stack.  They just had different sub-domains (dev1 vs www).  Never found a place where the code was different.

Comment: That is great +1, but.. any idea why??